# Finding morphisms beetwen formulas in category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, morphism

Let two formulas A and B are isomorphic when there are $f:A\vdash B$ and $g:B\vdash A$ such that the compositions $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are equal respectivly to the identity derivations on A and B.
I want to find these morphisms $f$ and $g$ in the case of two formulas $(A\land B)\rightarrow C$ and $B\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C)$.
Using adjunction (conjunction and implication as the left and the right adjoint), I see the following:
$$((A\land B)\rightarrow C,B\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))\simeq (B\land ((A\land B)\rightarrow C),A\rightarrow C)\simeq (A\land (B\land ((A\land B)\rightarrow C)),C)$$, 
then natural isomorphism and counit of adjunction.
I just need a help for explicit defining morphisms $f$ and $g$ which compositions will be identities.

Comment: It looks like you're working in a category where arrows are proofs/derivations. What exactly counts as a proof, and what is your definition of equality of proofs?

Comment: In this category of proofs, is there any non-identity isomorphism?

Comment: I am sorry for being not precise. Yes, object are formulas and arrows are derivations. Beside identity, there are $c_{A,B}: A\land B \vdash B\land A, \eta_{A,B}: B\vdash A\rightarrow (A\land B), \epsilon_{A,B}:A\land (A\rightarrow B )\vdash B, \alpha _{A,B,C}: A\land (B\land C)\vdash (A\land B)\land C$, and there are set of axioms that make make this category be simetrical non-strict monoidal closed ($\land$ is the bifunctor) If it is necessary, I can list these 12 axioms.

Comment: @AlexKruckman These axioms together with $(A\rightarrow \epsilon_{A,B}) \circ \eta_{A,A\rightarrow B}=1_{A\rightarrow B}$, say that for every A the functor F mapping $B$ to $A\land B$ and $f$ to $1_{A}\land f$ is a left adjoint for the functor G mapping $B$ to $A \rightarrow B$ and $f$ to $A\rightarrow f$.

Comment: @HeinrichD The unit of this adjunction is the natural transformation $\eta_{A}$ and counit is natural transformation $\epsilon_{A}$. Triangular identities for this adjunction are axioms: $$\epsilon_{A,A\land B}\circ (1_{A}\land (A\rightarrow f))=f\circ \epsilon_{A,B}$$  $$(A\rightarrow \epsilon_{A,B})\circ \eta_{A,A\rightarrow B}=1_{A\rightarrow B}$$